# ALTER TABLE mysql error

Tags: mysql, alter

I have create .sql file have a code like this:

```
ALTER TABLE `tb_1` ADD `ex1` TINYINT( 1 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
ALTER TABLE `tb_2` ADD `ex2` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1'
ALTER TABLE `tb_3` ADD `ex2` varchar(35) NOT NULL
```

and I always get error when I try to import it to db.

And only work if I import one line by line.

What is the problem please?

Comment: Use a `;` after each statement.

Comment: In the future if you get an error, please include it in your question.  Simply saying that you get an error in not enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have consecutive SQL statements, you should terminate them with a `;`

```
ALTER TABLE `tb_1` ADD `ex1` TINYINT( 1 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0';
ALTER TABLE `tb_2` ADD `ex2` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1';
ALTER TABLE `tb_3` ADD `ex2` varchar(35) NOT NULL;
```